# How to configure ContextMenu buttons for delete and disabled in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, contextmenu, swiftui, ios13

I tried to configure the button in the `contextMenu`, but it's not working.

```
Text("A label that have context menu")
    .contextMenu {
        Button(action: {
            // remove it
        }) {
            Text("Remove")
                .foregroundColor(.red) // Not working
            Image(systemName: "trash")
        }.disabled(true) // Not working
    }
```

what I have:

[image: Not working appearance]

What I'm seeking: (**delete** and **call** buttons)

[image: Demo]

I would create a `UIAction` like the following in `UIKit` but I can't find any modifier or anyway to bring this to the **SwiftUI**:

```
let delete = UIAction(title: "Remove", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive) { action in
    // remove it
}
```

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Please file a bug report.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All of the asked situations are now supported in **iOS 15**

#### Destructive: (works from iOS 15)

Set `.destructive` as the `role` argument of the button:

```
Button(role: .destructive) { //  This argument
    // delete something
} label: {
    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
}
```

[image: Delete Demo]

---

#### Disabled: (works from iOS 14.2)

Add `.disabled` modifier to the button.

```
Button {
    // call someone
} label: {
    Label("Call", systemImage: "phone")
}.disabled(true) //  This modifier
```

[image: Disabled Demo]

---

#### Divider: (works from iOS 14)

Use a `Divider()` view directly.

[image: Divider Demo]

---

#### Full Demo:

[image: Demo]
<sub>⚠️ Remember! Do **not** use `image` instead of `systemImage` for showing an SFSymbol on the button!</sub>

Answer (score 13):

### iOS 15+

Starting with iOS 15 we can add a `role` to a Button, so it can automatically adapt its appearance:

[image]

Here is an example:

```
Text("A label that have context menu")
    .contextMenu {
        Button(role: .destructive) {
            print("removing...")
        } label: {
            Text("Remove")
            Image(systemName: "trash")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Toggling a boolean that determines if the view is visible works:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textVisible = true
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if textVisible {
                Text("Hello World")
                .contextMenu {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.textVisible = false
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Remove")
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, since the context menu is attached to the `Text` that was removed, it will be permanently removed unless you having something else (e.g a `Button`) that toggles the boolean (`textVisible` in this case).

**Edit**: OP wanted to know how to make buttons in the context menu disabled/destructive (grey/red foreground colors), but I believe that as of October 20, 2019, SwiftUI has a bug that doesn't allow any buttons in the context menu to be any color other than red. Otherwise, setting the button as `.disabled(true)` should give it a grey color and disable it, and setting the button's foreground color to red (`foregroundColor(.red)`) should make the button destructive.

Comment: You answer is mostly fine. Just the Else part is not necessary.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I want to configure buttons to be **destructive (red)**, or **disabled (gray and inactive)**

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Sorry for misinterpreting! I think SwiftUI has a bug right now where context menu options can't change colors, they can only be black. You might find it beneficial to file a bug report.

Comment: To those downvoting: OP changed his question __after__ I posted my answer. The initial wording of the question made it seem like the OP only needed to know how to delete a view with a context menu. I'm not deleting my answer since it is the only answer on this question and I still think it is relevant to the question and could be useful for people.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is promoting use the Menu rather than ContextMenu. If you are looking to disable options in the Menu you can use the following code. You can use expression inside the modifier to make it dynamic

Regarding Styling - Currently it is not possible to style the individual items within the Menu. Even, if you apply the styling it will not work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Menu("Actions") {
                Button("Duplicate", action: {})
                Button("Rename", action: {})
                Button(action: {}) {
                    
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                    
                }.disabled(true)
                Button(action: {}) {
                   
                    Label("Call", systemImage: "phone")
                    
                }.disabled(true)
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Diasbled Menu Options]