# SwiftUI contextMenu - how add red (dangerous) actions

Tags: contextmenu, swiftui

This is a simple contextMenu.
1) How can I set Text("delete") and Image **red**.

2) How add divider (image below)

[image]

```
struct customMenu: View {

    var onDelete: (() -> Void)? 

    init(onDelete: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.onDelete = onDelete;
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (self.onDelete != nil) {
                Button(action: self.onDelete!) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("delete") 
                        Image(systemName: "trash") 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me the code how you use contextmenu?

Comment: It's not supported yet. I already asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467846/how-to-configure-contextmenu-buttons-for-delete-and-disabled-in-swiftui)

Comment: Thanks! My question is double https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467846/how-to-configure-contextmenu-buttons-for-delete-and-disabled-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, just enter the following:

```
Divider()
```