# SwiftUI destructive Button style

Tags: button, swiftui

is there a way to get a destructive `Button` style in SwiftUI?
I know I can do this for a `ContextMenu`, but I did not find a way for "normal" `Button`.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Button`:

```swift
Button("Tap") {
    // do something
}
.foregroundColor(.red)
```

For `Alert`:

```swift
Alert(
    title: Text("Hi"),
    message: Text("Do it?"),
    primaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel")),
    secondaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
        // do something
    }
)
```

And  similarly for `ActionSheet`.

Answer (score 31):

## iOS 15

From iOS 15 You can (and you should!) assign a `Role` to each button like:

```
Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
     deleteSomething()
}
```

Assigning the role to a button helps the system to apply the proper style for each context that uses the button (for example like **[this example for a context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893469/5623035)**)

#### More customization

You can create a combination of modifiers to create the needed style.

#### Demo

[image: Demo]

#### Code for above example:

```
VStack {
            
      Button("Plain", role: .none, action: { })
      .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

      Button("Automatic", role: .none, action: { })
      .buttonStyle(.automatic)

      Button("Log out", role: .cancel, action: { })
      .buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle())
      .tint(.yellow)

      // with controlSize
      Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: { })
      .buttonStyle(.borderless)
      .controlSize(.small)
      .tint(.yellow)

      Button("Delete", role: .destructive, action: { })
      .buttonStyle(.bordered)
      .controlSize(.regular)

      // with controlProminence
      Button(role: .destructive, action: { }, label: {
          Text("Exit").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

      })
      .buttonStyle(.bordered)
      .controlSize(.large)
      .controlProminence(.increased)

      //with BorderedShape
      Button(role: .destructive, action: { }, label: {
          Text("Wow shape").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      })
      .buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle(shape: .capsule))
      .controlSize(.large)
      .controlProminence(.increased)
      .tint(.purple)
}
```