# How to change contextMenu color(e.g. red) in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, swiftui, contextmenu

The following code will generate a context menu with black label on it.

[image]

But I'm looking for a way to creat effect like the image below. The "Remove App" with red colour. The foregroundColor modifier does not work in this case.

[image]

Comment: Not possible with SwiftUI (yet). See [How to configure ContextMenu buttons for delete and disabled in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58467846/8697793)

Comment: You can custom label like [this](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/12/23/labels-in-swiftui/)